# Umbraco rich text editor doesn't save html tag <code> (converts it to <p> (version 6)

Tags: html, rich-text-editor, umbraco6

When saving content marked as "< code >", inserted either via html or in the text editor, umbraco refuses to save the content as it is. Umbraco instead converts all < code > tags to < p > tags. This happens in the Rich text editor.
What do I have to do to make Umbraco understand that it can save html tags of the < code > type?

The version is 6.1.5

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `tinyMCEConfig.confg` you have to insert the `code` tag among the [validElements](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Config-files/tinyMceConfig/#validElements) node

Comment: Haha, had forgotten about this question. Of course it's the correct answer :)